# Writing a shapely object to a database

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, geopandas

I'm having a bit of trouble with writing a shapely object to a database and there seems to be limited resources regarding my issue out there. I have a dataframe as follows:

```
         RecAreaName RecAreaCategory Province Comments                                        coordinates
0           Whistler     World Class       BC     None  POLYGON ((-123.052382 50.094969, -123.050613 5...
1    Tofino Ucluelet     World Class       BC     None  POLYGON ((-125.946713 49.24364400000002, -126....
2              Banff     World Class       AB     None  POLYGON ((-115.564478 51.11632900000002, -115....
3            Canmore     World Class       AB     None  POLYGON ((-115.396185 51.07281599999998, -115....
4        Lake Louise     World Class       AB     None  POLYGON ((-116.275023 51.43238300000001, -116....
..               ...             ...      ...      ...                                                ...
159   Ski Chantecler            None       QC     None  POLYGON ((-74.18784099999998 45.96117599999999...
160      Belle Niege            None       QC     None  POLYGON ((-74.215389 45.99528800000001, -74.20...
161       Valée Blue            None       QC     None  POLYGON ((-74.245796 46.03202199999999, -74.23...
162      Ski Garceau            None       QC     None  POLYGON ((-74.22637400000001 46.34051399999998...
163   Ski La Reserve            None       QC     None  POLYGON ((-74.18463800000001 46.27545499999999...
```

Coordinates is a shapely Polygon object.
I am trying to write this to a database. The regular pandas method works (as long as I don't have a shapely object) as follows:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:maria@localhost:3306/topology?unix_socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock')
dataframe.to_sql(
        name='TestTable',
        con=engine,
        if_exists='fail')
```

My question is do I need geoalchemy to write to this dataframe to my database or can I do this with regular sqlalchemy or use SQL functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your geometry column using `to_wkt`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(gdf).assign(Coordinates=gdf['Coordinates'].to_wkt())
```

Now you can use `df` to upload data to database. The reverse operation:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.assign(Coordinates=df['Coordinates'].apply(wkt.loads)), geometry='Coordinates')
```

My [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html):

```
>>> gdf
           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude                  Coordinates
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66  POINT (-58.66000 -34.58000)
1      Brasilia     Brazil    -15.78     -47.91  POINT (-47.91000 -15.78000)
2      Santiago      Chile    -33.45     -70.66  POINT (-70.66000 -33.45000)
3        Bogota   Colombia      4.60     -74.08    POINT (-74.08000 4.60000)
4       Caracas  Venezuela     10.48     -66.86   POINT (-66.86000 10.48000)

>>> gdf.info()
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------       --------------  -----   
 0   City         5 non-null      object  
 1   Country      5 non-null      object  
 2   Latitude     5 non-null      float64 
 3   Longitude    5 non-null      float64 
 4   Coordinates  5 non-null      geometry
dtypes: float64(2), geometry(1), object(2)
memory usage: 328.0+ bytes
```

Comment: So currently my dataframe is just a normal dataframe, it isn't a geopandas dataframe. So I would just need to convert it to a wkt format by running the following code: `dataframe=dataframe.assign(Coordinates=dataframe['Coordinates'].to_wkt())` and then just run the `dataframe.sql`?

Comment: Yes. I think. If you convert column 'coordinates' to string, there's no reason it won't work

Comment: It would work but this would upload the Polygon as a string, instead of type 'geom' in my database. Maybe I could run a SQL process to convert it from a string to geom from python?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know SQLAlchemy very well. I just know you can apply this MySQL function `ST_GeomFromText` to a text field to convert text to a geometry.

Comment: The thing is changing a column from text to geom type in SQL isn't easy, that's why I was hoping there was a way to directly upload my coordinates as a geom type into SQL